# How to change DataFrame column value base on one column value and other conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame and Series condition, like following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range('20170801','20170805')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sales:[5,10,15,20,25]'}, index = dates)
error_days = pd.Series([True, True,False, False, True], index=df.index)
```

So, df is

```
             Sales
2017-08-01      5
2017-08-02     10
2017-08-03     15
2017-08-04     20
2017-08-05     25
```

error_days is

```
2017-08-01     True
2017-08-02     True
2017-08-03    False
2017-08-04    False
2017-08-05     True
```

I would change Sales for those error_days to 8 if original sales>8, so df result is

```
             Sales
2017-08-01      5
2017-08-02     8
2017-08-03     15
2017-08-04     20
2017-08-05     8
```

How to do it?

I know

```
df['sales'][error_days] = 8
```

will change all the values, but I only want to change those sales>8 to 8.

BTW, Please don't add a new column to df.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC we can use [Series.clip_upper()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html) here:

```
In [12]: df.loc[error_days, 'Sales'] = df.loc[error_days, 'Sales'].clip_upper(8)

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
            Sales
2017-08-01      5
2017-08-02      8
2017-08-03     15
2017-08-04     20
2017-08-05      8
```

Answer (score 2):

First need chained conditions by `&` with another mask `df['Sales'] > 8`.

**1.**

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[error_days & (df['Sales'] > 8), 'Sales'] = 8 
print (df)
            Sales
2017-08-01      5
2017-08-02      8
2017-08-03     15
2017-08-04     20
2017-08-05      8
```

**2.**

Or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Sales'] = df['Sales'].mask(error_days & (df['Sales'] > 8), 8) 
print (df)
            Sales
2017-08-01      5
2017-08-02      8
2017-08-03     15
2017-08-04     20
2017-08-05      8
```

**3.**

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Sales'] = np.where(error_days & (df['Sales'] > 8), 8, df['Sales']) 
print (df)
            Sales
2017-08-01      5
2017-08-02      8
2017-08-03     15
2017-08-04     20
2017-08-05      8
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But that doesn't meet my requirements, I only need change those sales>8 to 8, so 2017-08-01 5 should be kept. would you mind check again?

Comment: Sorry, i think it was typo.

Comment: So cool, all of them works good. It seems I cannot vote 2 answers in one question. But I do want to say thank you.